# how to concurrently put an element (might exist) without lock in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, message-queue, concurrenthashmap

I'm writing a simple message queue program and I have **multiple producers** and **multiple serializer** (consumer is not considered right now). The producer specifies which queue it want to send message to by using a `String queueName`. And the serializer could **only be initialized during sending procedure** because the exact number/name of queues are not known until running. Since I have to use a Map, I think I can use either

- HashMap together with lock/synchronized
- ConcurrentHashMap

I want to avoid using explicit lock, so I choose ConcurrentHashMap. However, using `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't mean my program `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe, the idle between `containsKey()` and `put()` might cause some chaos. So I consider using its `putIfAbsent()` method.

However, when I call `putIfAbsent(queuename, new MySerializer())`, I find it creates a new instance of `MySerializer` everytime I call putIfAbsent. But if I don't use `putIfAbsent`, I'll have to use something like a lock.

My question is how to concurrently add elements into ConcurrentHashMap while avoiding using lock at the same time?

Comment: `Map.computeIfAbsent(queuename, MySerializer::new)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks, it's a good solution. I'll accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 8 added new methods to the `Map` interface which allow the potentially-new value to be evaluated lazily. For example:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(queuename, MySerializer::new);
```